# How to extract max elevation values for each road links in a shapefile using Python libraries?

Tags: python, geopandas, zonal-statistics, rasterio, rasterstats

I want to extract values from a raster DEM file for each feature (polyline) in a shapefile. For each feature in a road shapefile, I want to extract the max and min elevation within a buffer (say 10 ft) of that line.

I am looking for a function similar to AddSurfaceInformation_3d from ESRI ArcGIS.

I attempted using GeoPandas and rasterio with no success. I am receiving only null values.

```
import geopandas as gpd
gdf = gpd.read_file(pth_to_road_shapefile)

from rasterstats import zonal_stats
with rasterio.open("path_to_test.tif") as src:
    affine = src.transform
    array = src.read(1)
    df_zonal_stats = pd.DataFrame(zonal_stats(gdf, array, affine=affine))

gdf2 = pd.concat([gdf, df_zonal_stats], axis=1)
```

Example DEM and vector shapefile [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/my9as72pasnb7z4/AADpePfb20hyNfLiSothjz0Ba?dl=0)

Comment: Possible to share in input files?

Comment: Could try geocube: https://corteva.github.io/geocube/stable/examples/zonal_statistics.html

Comment: Have you tried plotting them and made sure they overlap?

Comment: Does your raster have areas of no data i.e. null? If so that may be the source of the null result.

Comment: @BERA Yes, they overlap.

Comment: @CharlieParr My raster has areas with no data; would this be an issue? Not all features lie in areas with no data. Finally, I am able to get the correct resutls when using AddSurfaceInformation_3d from ArcGIS. Thanks

Comment: Possibly - although if every single feature result is null then perhaps there is another underlying issue. Difficult to say - post some sample data if you can.

Comment: @CharlieParr Thanks a lot. I modified the post to include links to sample data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your raster DEM and vector road shapefile have different coordinate systems. They need a common coordinate reference system for the rasterstats package to compute the zonal statistics.

```
import rasterio
import geopandas as gpd
import rasterstats as rs
src = rasterio.open('example_dem.tif')
gdf = gpd.read_file('example_road.shp')
gdf.crs
```

{'init': 'epsg:4326'}

```
src.meta['crs']
```

CRS.from_wkt('PROJCS["NAD83 / Texas South Central (ftUS)",GEOGCS["NAD83",DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6269"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4269"]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",27.8333333333333],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-99],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",30.2833333333333],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",28.3833333333333],PARAMETER["false_easting",1968500],PARAMETER["false_northing",13123333.333],UNIT["US survey foot",0.304800609601219,AUTHORITY["9003","EPSG"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH]]')

As you can see these two CRS are not the same. To rectify, we can reproject the road shapefile to the DEM CRS.

```
# Project it
proj_gdf = gdf.to_crs(src.meta['crs'])
# Check the new CRS
proj_gdf.crs
```

RS.from_wkt('PROJCS["NAD83 / Texas South Central (ftUS)",GEOGCS["NAD83",DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6269"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4269"]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",27.8333333333333],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-99],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",30.2833333333333],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",28.3833333333333],PARAMETER["false_easting",1968500],PARAMETER["false_northing",13123333.333],UNIT["US survey foot",0.304800609601219,AUTHORITY["9003","EPSG"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH]]')

Now you can see it is the same! We are now ready to perform the zonal statistics:

```
stats=['min', 'max']
arr = src.read(1)
affine = src.transform
zonal_stats = (rs.zonal_stats(proj_gdf, arr, stats=stats, affine=affine))
```

Now inspect `zonal_stats`:

`[{'min': 0.1312335878610611, 'max': 40.10498809814453},
 {'min': 5.505249500274658, 'max': 30.498685836791992},
 {'min': 16.5944881439209, 'max': 38.684383392333984}]`

Comment: You solved my problem. Thanks a lot for your time and kindness. Appreciate it!